# How to use ng-repeat to access object of objects based on condition

Tags: angularjs

I have an object having this structure:

```
sample_object{
   {  
      Parent_node1{
            {
                child_node1{bool:true,xyz:abc},
                child_node2{bool:false,xyz:abc},
                child_node3{bool:true,xyz:abc}
            }
          },
      Parent_node2{
                 {
                child_node1{bool:true,xyz:abc},
                child_node2{bool:false,xyz:abc},
                child_node3{bool:true,xyz:abc}
            }
          },
      Parent_node3{'similar structure'}
   }

}
```

I want to display something like this using ng-repeat:-

Parent_node : child_node1,child_node2,child_node3

Only those child_nodes having bool value as true should be displayed; and parent_node which has no true bool value for any child should not be displayed.
Confused as anything.Any insight is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-repeat` directive with (key, value) because as far as I see you have to iterate an object instead of an array.

Your code should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyParent, parent) in sample_object" >
    <div ng-repeat="(keyChild, child) in parent">
        <div ng-if="child.bool">
               {{child.xyz}} 
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: do i just write "keyparent" and "keychild" or do they stand for any attribute in parent and child resp.?

Comment: you can pick the name that you want, they will iterate over the keys of your object. In every iteration (key,value) key will represent the key of the object and value the object in that property.

Comment: i tried using it but it still doesnot work for me. is there any other way to write the same? i also need the parent nodes displayed as well.

Comment: Could you please add all together in a plunkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131621/discussion-between-separ1-and-manuel-obregozo).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyParent, parent) in sample_object" >
    <div ng-repeat="(keyChild, child) in parent">
        <p ng-if="child.bool">
               {{child.xyz}} 
        </p>
    </div>    
</div>

<tr ng-repeat="sample in sample_object">
    <td ng-repeat="keys in sample">
        {{keys.xyz}}
    </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: can you give me an example to understand the (keyParent,parent) attribute better?

Comment: ng-repeat is same like foreach. go through foreach. Two ng-repeat think two foreach